# Solve conflict between Electron and Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have a php webpage where I'm using Reactjs 15.6.2 with React-js-search. (two simple included .js files)

It is working well in any browser, but as soon as I open this page with my electron app (I'm using `window.open`, React is failing.

I can make it work normally if I give to `window.open` : `nodeIntegration=no`.

But after that electron functionality aren't working : `const remote = require('electron').remote` and 
`var fs = require('fs');` are in the same file.

Is it possible to have both ? Can i just ask to integrate electron without messing up my reactjs setup ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know you were a programmer apart from a Folk legend.

One problem that comes up a lot in electron when you are using "like a website" is that some dependencies check if they are running on Node or the browser. After doing said check they either use commonJS export or expose a global variable.

I'm not sure how are you setting things up, but if you want to have node integration on you shouldn't rely on global variables.

If you are using React, you could do something like this:

Install react in the terminal inside your project

```
npm install --save react
```

Require react where you are planning on using it.

```
const React = require('react')

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hello and thanks for answering. It's a php webpage that opens a new php page. I've done : `npm install react react-dom create-react-class --save` and added to the second php page `var React = require('react');var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');` and changed the code I had with `var App = createReactClass({displayName: "Test",render: function render(){....` but It seems `render` isn't working now, I have : `React.render is not a function`. This is where I'm stuck for now...

Comment: Ok. I see. Normally, the best approach would be to not render your page from PHP when using electron, but having your page render in Electron and then get the data from an API you can build. If you still prefer to render from PHP, they you should consider using WebView, Iframe or BrowserView (https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-view). In that case you'll be using Electron more like a browser. But if you want to have NodeJS capabilities, then write and run your HTML and JS inside Electron and call an API for getting data from the back.

Comment: Sorry yes, that's what I'm using in my `main.js` : `Window = new BrowserWindow({show: false})` So this is where my problems are.